# Errors in Android app

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

How can I see the errors occurred in my code? I am working in Eclipse.

How to check what has caused the error when an application is stopped or asked to be force closed in emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the ouput of the `LogCat`.

There's a corresponding View, which can be opened by choosing :

```
Window > Show View > Other > Android > LogCat
```

Generally speaking, when an error occurs, a stack-trace will be displayed in the LogCat, giving you some informations about that error.